# Find all $a$ for a unique solution of $y'=[\cos(x+2y)+ay]^{\frac{4}{5}}$ with $y(0)=2\pi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find all values of $a\in \mathbb{R}$ for which the IVP $y'=[\cos(x+2y)+ay]^{\frac{4}{5}}$ with $y(0)=2\pi$
> has solution in some neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)=(0,2\pi)$. For which values of $a$ is this solution unique?

*Attempt* Let $D=\{(x,y):|x|\leqslant A,~|y-2\pi|\leqslant B\}$ and $f(x,y)=[\cos(x+2y)+ay]^{\frac{4}{5}}$ is continuous on $D$ as long as
$\cos(x+2y)+ay\geqslant 0$ for all $(x,y)\in D$. In that case,  theorem of Peano guarantees the existence of a solution, as wanted. To find all $a$ though, we have $a\geqslant -\min_{(x,y)\in D}\frac{\cos(x+2y)}{y}$, which implies two issues:

$\bullet$ how could we evaluate the above minimum?

$\bullet$ even if we evaluate the min above, it would depend on the values $A,B$ of the rectangle $D$. I would expect an answer independent of $A,\,B$, meaning that we could work for all regions of   $(x_0,y_0)=(0,2\pi)$.

For the next part of course, we could apply the Picard - Lindelof theorem, as long as $f_y(x,y)=\frac45\,[\cos(x+2y)+ay]^{-\frac{1}{5}} [a-2\sin(x+2y)]$
is bounded on $D$, that is
$\cos(x+2y)+ay>0$ for all $(x,y)\in D$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You only want local solution why do you want to solve the minimum? The existence only needs the function continuous around your init point. So just make $A$ and $B$ as small as possible

Comment: Finding all the desired $a$ implies finding $-\min_D\frac{\cos(x+2y)}{y}$. How else could we find $a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am far from the differential equations, but can easily answer the question about minimum.
Namely, the function $g(x,y)=\frac{\cos(x+2y)}{y}$ is continuous at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ and
$g(x_0,y_0)=\frac 1{2\pi}$. That is, if $a>-\frac 1{2\pi}$ iff for some neighborhood $D\subset \mathbb R^2\setminus\mathbb R\times\{0\}$ of $(x_0,y_0)$ we have $a>-\inf_{(x,y)\in D} g(x_,y)$.

Comment: Indeed, for $a>-\frac{1}{2\pi}$ function $(x,y) \mapsto \cos(x+2y)+ay$ maps $(x_0,y_0)=(0,2\pi)$ to $1+2\pi a>0$, so it is positive (due to continuity) in a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$. Thanks!